# Will Method called in for loop with Update statement(dml) will have governerLimit Issue

Tags: apex, trigger, code, business-logic

I have below requirement ,i have called method in for loop ,i want to know
1.Will this cause an Dml governer limit issue?
2.how we can optimize the below code
**Requirements - Update Primary contact on Account, If no primary
contact(check box in contact) found then take older(createdDate) contact and update in
account and mark contact as Primary
thanks in advance**

```
      /******************************************************************
      Description: - Update Primary contact on Account, If no primary
      conntact then take older contact and update in account
      and mark contact as Primary
      ******************************************************************/
         public class UpdatePrimaryContactOnAccount {
              public static void updatePrimaryContact(list<account>accList) {
               set<id> accIds = new set<id>();
                for(account ac:accList) {
                   accIds.add(ac.id);
                }
              map<id,contact> primaryContactMap = new map<id,contact>();
              for(contact con:[select id,accountid from contact where accountid in :accIds and 
                               PrimaryContact__c=true]) {
                   primaryContactMap.put(con.accountId,con); //get primary contact of account
              }
              for(account acc:accList) {
                 if (primaryContactMap.containsKey(acc.Id) == false) { // if no primary 
                        contact of account
              acc.Contact__c = getOldContact(acc); // this method get oldcreated contact and 
                        update contact
            }
              else {
                acc.Contact__c = primaryContactMap.get(acc.Id).id;
           }
      }
 }

//this method gets oldcreatedContact and update contact primaryContact__c checkbox true
public static id getOldContact(account accList) {
    id ids ;
    list<contact>conUpdate = new list<contact>();
    for(contact con :[select id from contact where accountid =:accList.id  order by 
      createdDate asc limit 1]) {
        con.PrimaryContact__c = true;
        ids = con.id;
        conUpdate.add(con);
    }
    update conUpdate;
    return ids;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this cause an Dml governer limit issue?

Yes, you'll run out of DML operations when you approach 75 records.

> how we can optimize the below code[?]

```
public static void updatePrimaryContact(list<account>accList) {
    Map<Id, Account> secondaryContacts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT (SELECT PrimaryContact__c FROM Contacts ORDER BY PrimaryContact__c DESC, CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account WHERE Id = :accList]);
    Contact[] updatedContacts = new Contact[0];
    for(account acc:accList) {
        Contacts[] = acc.Contacts;
        if(acc.Contacts.size() > 0) {
            Contact primaryContact = acc.Contacts[0];
            if(!primaryContact.PrimaryContact__c) {
                primaryContact.PrimaryContact__c = true;
                updatedContacts.add(primaryContact);
            }
            acc.Contact__c = primaryContact.Id;
        } else {
            acc.Contact__c = null;
        }
    }
    update updatedContacts;
}
```

We can just use a single sub-query, and return by PrimaryContact__c DESC (so, the primary contact will be returned first, if any), followed by the oldest contact. We then add those contacts to the list if the box was checked.

Comment: awesome.. sfdcfox.. let me try . but if i want to optimize my existing code by changing or modifying something in  acc.Contact__c = getOldContact(acc); in this line where i am calling other method. how i can do it. just for my understanding

Comment: @santu You still need to query before calling the method repeatedly, and update the contacts only after you've updated all of the contacts.